# autoref for algorithms

Tags: hyperref, labels, algorithms, algorithmicx, autoref

```
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

So when I

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Baseline}\label{ALG_baseline}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
...
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

the output will look somewhat like this:

```
--------------------------------------
Algorithm 1: Baseline
--------------------------------------
...
--------------------------------------
```

So obviously, there IS a counter, already.

But

```
\autoref{ALG_baseline} is simply linked to with a number.
```

will result int

```
[1] is simply linked to with a number.
```

How can I make autoref output

```
[Algorithm 1] is ...
```

instead?

Comment: `\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}`, assuming that the counter is named `algorithm`. Please post a compilable document, not just fragments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`\autoref` does only work completely with a corresponding `\....autorefname` macro, i.e. `\sectionautorefname` etc.

`hyperref` extracts the reference information from its specific label information, where the relevant counter name is stored as well.

This means, if the counter is named `foo`, `\fooautorefname` must exist -- otherwise it's ignored (and a warning shipped to the console).

The `algorithm` environment has a counter of the same name, so

```
\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
```

will provide `hyperref` with the correct information.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Baseline}\label{ALG_baseline}
%\begin{algorithmic}[1]
%
%\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\autoref{ALG_baseline} is simply linked to with a number.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note, that `cleveref` package provides a similar feature, however, the names must be setup as well, with `\crefname{algorithm}{algorithm}{algorithms}` etc.

**Update**

This addresses the comment by the O.P. about detecting names of counters.

An excerpt of the `.log` file:

The counter definitions are written to the `.log` file as `c@foo=\countY`, where `Y` is the number of a free counter register and not really important (apart from few exceptions.)

```
\@float@every@algorithm=\toks16
\c@algorithm=\count88
```

Later on, we find

```
\c@ALG@line=\count89
\c@ALG@rem=\count90
\c@ALG@nested=\count91
\ALG@tlm=\skip43
\ALG@thistlm=\skip44
\c@ALG@Lnr=\count92
\c@ALG@blocknr=\count93
\c@ALG@storecount=\count94
\c@ALG@tmpcounter=\count95
\ALG@tmplength=\skip45
```

This means, that `ALG@line` is (very likely) the line number counter.

However, it's a 'hidden' counter, due to `@` usage in the name!

Comment: Thank you. You say "the ``algorithm`` environment has a counter of the same name". How/Where do I find this information? Where would I find the name of the line-counter mentioned in its documentation? http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf#section.5

Comment: @User1291: Look for `\newcounter` statements in the `.sty` file or have a look on the `.log` file , see my edits to my answer at the end, please

Comment: +1. The `cleveref` package has known about the `algorithm` package since version 0.17. (Current version: 0.19 or so.) Both `\Cref{ALG_baseline}` and`\cref{ALG_baseline}` work right away -- no need for `\crefname{algorithm}{algorithm}{algorithms}`, etc.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks, I should have looked into `cleveref.cfg` The better, others do not have to define the `\crefname` then

Answer (score 2):

I took me half an our to figure out that I had to use \renewcommand{} instead of just \newcommand to overwrite the hyperref default algorithm name.