# Create a smart cross-reference to a line in an 'algorithmic' environment using \autoref

Tags: cross-referencing, algorithms, algorithmicx, autoref

To set the name of the `\autoref` command for an algorithm I use:

```
\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}
```

like commented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313508/87200). I would also like to be able to refer to lines within an `algorithmic` environment with `line x`.

```
\begin{algorithm}
\label{alg:myalg}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State Do X 
  \State Do Y \label{algl:y}
  \State $x = y + z$
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

`\autoref{alg:myalg}` gives me correctly *Algorithm 1*. In addition, I would also like to have `\autoref{algl:y}` generate *line 2*. Until now I'm using: `line~\ref{algl:y}`.

Seeing the [same answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313508/87200) you can define the autoref names by: `\....autorefname`.
But then he mentions that some counters are hidden, for example the line numbering: `\c@ALG@line`. Is it possible to create an autoref name for them?

I have tried:

```
\newcommand{\ALGlineautorefname}{line}
\newcommand{\ALG_lineautorefname}{line}
\newcommand{\ALG@lineautorefname}{line}
```

but none work and only the first compiles.

If possible, how can I create an `\autorefname` for a line in an `algorithmic` environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line counter is hidden from [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `\autoref` because the counter is stepped using `\addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}` instead of `\refstepcounter{ALG@line}`. The following patch corrects this, allowing you to define `\ALG@lineautorefname`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ALG@step}{\addtocounter{ALG@line}{1}}{\refstepcounter{ALG@line}}{}{}
\newcommand{\ALG@lineautorefname}{Line}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}

\begin{document}  

See \autoref{alg:myalg}, specifically \autoref{algl:y}.

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{An algorithm}\label{alg:myalg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \State Do X 
    \State Do Y \label{algl:y}
    \State $x = y + z$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. What's nice about this solution is that it doesn't interfere with `cleveref`'s own patch of the counter-incrementing setting of the `algorithmic` environment. That way, should the OP or some future readers of this posting decide to use the `cleveref` package as well, they won't need to undo the patch shown above.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work well, but with `pdflatex` it refers to the lines of the first algorithm (if there are more).

Comment: I'm using algorithm2e and this patch doesn't seem to work - any ideas what changes might be required to adjust the \autoref text for a line in an algorithm2e block?

Comment: @aaronsnoswell: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/wRLLYPMt). `\autoref`-ing a line number uses `\AlgoLineautorefname`.

Comment: @Werner amazing thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work in the case of multiple algorithms; the first time a line number appears in any algorithm, all labels to that line number in other algorithms will cause a hyperlink to be produced to the first line that had that number, not the line with the label. A solution is found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/687624/203081).

Answer (score 2):

The following is a `cleveref`-based solution. Note: `\cref` (the main user macro of the `cleveref` package) works very much like `\autoref`, except that it's actually far more powerful and flexible than `\autoref`. For instance, `\cref` can take multiple arguments; see the code below for an example. Further good news: `cleveref` is programmed "out of the box" to know that lines in an `algorithmic` environment should be called, well, "lines" -- no need to provide this setup yourself.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Baseline}\label{ALG_baseline}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \State Do X 
  \State Do Y        \label{algl:y}
  \State $x = y + z$ \label{algl:sum}
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\cref{algl:y} in \cref{ALG_baseline} is \dots

\cref{algl:y,algl:sum} of the algorithm are based on \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about this packages it sounds even better than autoref. However, when I tried it it actually referred to a line of another algorithm, but I'll try to solve that later.

Comment: @agold - Could you provide a bit more information about the the cross-reference that's going astray? E.g., what do the `\label` instructions look like for the two lines?

Comment: Actually I found that it was due to the use of `pdflatex` (like with the solution of Werner), with `latex` it works correctly.

Comment: @agold - Hmm, not sure I understood what you just wrote. `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and `lualatex` are the combinations of the `LaTeX` *format* and the `pdftex`, `xetex`, and `luatex` *engines*, respectively. What exactly do you run when you run "`latex`"?

Comment: sorry for the confusion; I mean that compiling with `latex` and then doing `dvipdf` the references are correct, however when I compile with `pdflatex` I get the problem of all lines referring to the first algorithm.

Comment: @agold - Which TeX distribution (and which vintage) do you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52788/discussion-between-agold-and-mico).