# Capitalise cleveref reference of algorithm2e

Tags: hyperref, cleveref, algorithm2e

I'd like to reference an algorithm from `algorithm2e` using `hyperref` and `cleveref`. The goal is that "Algorithm" is capitalised in the reference. Neither using the `capitalise` option nor including manual reference names using

```
\crefname{algocf}{alg.}{algs.}
\Crefname{algocf}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}
```

works, unfortunately. A minimum example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}


\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}[t]
\SetAlgoLined
test
\caption{test algorithm}
\label{algo:test}
\end{algorithm}


Reference is \autoref{algo:test}.


\end{document}
```

Comment: You should use `\renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}` as described in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313507/autoref-for-algorithms).

Comment: I am seemingly worse at looking for duplicates than I thought previously. `\renewcommand{\algorithmautorefname}{Algorithm}` does the trick, thanks!

Comment: Your query is confusing: In the title of the query your refer to the `cleveref` package, but in the body of the query you use `\autoref`, a macro provided by the `hyperref` package, rather than either `\cref` or  \Cref`.

Comment: `\autoref` is from the `hyperref` package, not from `cleveref`, which uses `\cref`.  Your methods are for `\cref` and essentially work, but the counter is aliased to `algorithm`, so you need `\crefname{algorithm}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}`